# Set timeout duration equal to the time that it takes for the login process to run

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, jquery-animate

I'm trying to make a login form animate back outside the screen when the user logs in. The animation depends on an if statement which checks the current authentication state. However, in order for this statement to work I'm forced to set a `$timeout` so that the login request can be sent and the authentication state to be changed before the if statement is run.

As long as the request doesn't take longer than `1000 ms` (and this is also the bare minimum it must be set to) this works fine, but sometimes it does take longer. So my question is, how would I allow this duration to change depending on the time it took for the request to run? I don't want to set for example `3000 ms` and have the user wait if it doesn't have to if the request itself only took `1000 ms`.

The login process is done using Firebase, so it has to send a request to their API and then send back a response so that's why the duration is very inconsistent.

I run this animation from a directive which activates via two seperate buttons; one to display the actual form and one to confirm the information that the user has entered:

```
forumApp.directive('mySigninSlide', ['sharedInfo', '$timeout',
    function(sharedInfo, $timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function($scope, element, attrs) {

                /**
                 * Display/hide the login form via
                 * an animation depending on which
                 * button is clicked and the login state
                 */
                element.on('click', function() {

                    var sidebar = $('#signin-wrapper');

                    if (element.attr('id') === 'confirm-login-btn') {

                        $timeout(function() {

                            if (sharedInfo.getAuthState()) {

                                sidebar.stop().animate({left: '-606px'});
                                sharedInfo.setError('');
                                $scope.isAnimated = true;
                            }
                        //1000 ms is the bare minimum time
                        //it takes for the login process
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                    else {
                        if ($scope.isAnimated === undefined || 
                            $scope.isAnimated === false) {

                            sidebar.stop().animate({left: '340px'});
                            $scope.isAnimated = true;
                        }
                        else {
                            sidebar.stop().animate({left: '-606px'});
                            $scope.isAnimated = false;
                            sharedInfo.setError('');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
}]);
```

Comment: Your login should be an ajax call, than you should check auth-state in callback function. The way you try to do it now will never work correctly.

Comment: @skobaljic How would I call the directive from the callback then? Because the login process is an AJAX call at the moment. And the auth state is stored in a service so I can share it across controllers.

Comment: I would say: `send_login_data(url, data, callback: check_auth_state(url, data, callback: function( do_animations() ))` Everything must flow async.

Comment: @skobaljic DOM manipulation should only be done from within a directive though. Your solution would be bad practice I think.

Comment: If you have to use timeouts, than set them on shorter interval and call several times, up to 10 times for example or until you get new auth_state.

Comment: @skobaljic Care to provide an example of that?

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to check rapidly for auth-state (instead of one call `$timeout`) this way:

```
function checkState() {
    maxChecks--;
    if (sharedInfo.getAuthState()) {
        sidebar.stop().animate({left: '-606px'});
        sharedInfo.setError('');
        $scope.isAnimated = true;
    } else if ( maxChecks ) setTimeout(checkState, 100);
};
var maxChecks = 30;
setTimeout(checkState, 500);
```

Which means: wait half of second then check for **new** auth-state each .1 seconds.

I had to do this several times, but I am not fun of it. I suggest you find the way to do it asynchronously - the way it should be done.